# How to get quickly two data from this String data?

Tags: php

There is this String data from the column value of a table column : `/var/www/imfmobile/photoj2meupload/7455575/photo32.png`

I want to get the `7455575` and the `photo32.png` substring's. How to achieve that quickly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '/var/www/imfmobile/photoj2meupload/7455575/photo32.png';
$arr = explode('/', $str);
echo end($arr); // photo32.png
echo prev($arr); // 7455575
```

Answer (score 4):

use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string at `/`:

```
$parts = explode('/',$mystring);
```

and then just use [array_pop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to get the values:

```
$filename = array_pop($parts);
$foldername = array_pop($parts);
```

Comment: Just for notes, array_pop is slower than end()+prev();

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) functions:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/var/www/imfmobile/photoj2meupload/7455575/photo32.png');

echo basename( $path_parts['dirname'] ) . "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'] . "\n";
```

Will output:

```
7455575
photo32.png
```

Comment: i can't see how to get the name of the last folder containing the file - you can just get the complete folter-path.

Comment: This is the slowest way to do it btw. Almost twice slower than other methods.